# Trying to run a binary file inside Docker returns error 127

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a binary file from code that lives inside a Docker container, and I get a "Not found" 127 error.

The binary file I'm trying to run is at `~/blah/src/vendor/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64` It was installed with PHP Composer.

When I go to that directory in Linux (WSL for Windows, actually), I can see that file and run it just fine.

But when I try to get inside the container (using `docker exec -it php /bin/sh`), I see this:

```
/var/www/html/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin # whoami
root
/var/www/html/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin # ls -la
total 38880
drwxr-xr-x    2 laravel  laravel       4096 Feb  9 18:54 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 laravel  laravel       4096 Jan 15  2018 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 laravel  laravel   39804584 Jan 15  2018 wkhtmltopdf-amd64
/var/www/html/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin # ./wkhtmltopdf-amd64
/bin/sh: ./wkhtmltopdf-amd64: not found
```

How can it not be found if it's right there?!

I want code running in the container (PHP code) to be able to run that binary, but it can't.

Note: I'm not trying to run this command as a Docker command.  The Docker container is PHP, and PHP inside that container is trying to run this command.

Comment: Where are you getting that binary file from?  Independent of the PHP application, can you run it (`docker-compose run php /path/to/wkhtmltopdf-amd64`)?  Is overwriting the image's content with `volumes:` causing the binary to be lost?

Comment: Yes, David, that's how I did it.  I can see that file there.  If I run things like "ls" and "pwd" from exec() in PHP, I can see that binary file just sitting there.  But when I try running it with exec(), I get 127.  Also, if I WSL into Ubuntu (I'm developing in Windows), I can run the binary just fine.  Just not through Docker.

Comment: Please change the title as this is not PHP related problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a different docker image.  Instead of `php:7.4-fpm-alpine` I used `php:7.4-fpm`

This also allowed me to execute `bash` instead of `/bin/sh`

And in my php.dockerfile, I had to add a line to run to apt-get install some stuff.  In my case it was these: libxrender1, fontconfig, libxext6

Answer (score -1):

Please see https://superuser.com/questions/1511681/docker-not-found-and-invalid-handle-errors-for-linux-container-volumes-in-d

Maybe use the volume as per post above as this seems to be OS/Docker dependent issue.

```
version: '3.4'    
volumes:
       test_vol:
          driver: local
          driver_opts:
             type: none
             device: /host_mnt/c/path/to/folder
             o: bind
```

Comment: Thanks Maciej.  I'm not trying to run the command as a docker container with CMD.  I'm trying to run the command from PHP code in a .php file, which is served from nginx.  PHP and nginx are both docker containers (there are a few more too).  I added my question to add php.dockerfile.

Comment: I would suggest to just exec into a container bash and try to execute it by hand over there. Like docker exec -it name_of_container bash .This way you should be able to see more, and if you cannot see that put strace the command you want to launch.

Comment: OK, I did that, and it still says the file is not found, even when I'm right there, trying to run it.  I'll edit the question and add this.

Comment: Well so it's not the problem with PHP code but with the file accessibility can you output here ls -al ?

Comment: What operating system do you use as a Host ? And version of docker engine?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10.  I have Ubuntu installed in WSL.  Docker is 20.10.2.

Comment: As I said before this issue is not PHP related but OS related so please investigate that.